# How to add spec test to grape api in rails 2.3?

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-2, grape-api

all

I want to add rspec tests to grape API. and our app is still on rails 2.3.8 .

for the rspec 2+ , we have that solution.

```
https://github.com/dblock/grape/commit/99bf4b44c511541c0e10f4506bf34ae9abcccd75
```

but  is there a solution rspec 1.3? As rspec 2+ can't work on rails 2.3. but rails3 at least.

I digged the code, and can't find a example can help. anybody help? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec 1 does not have request specs, which is what is described.

You can use the Rails 2 integration testing framework to achieve the same result. You will have to run the test using test/unit though; since this will never be supported in RSpec 1.